# mock[Option[X509Certificate]].nonEmpty check

Tags: scala, mocking, x509certificate

I have below code:

```
val fakeExpiredCertificate = mock[Option[X509Certificate]]

println((fakeExpiredCertificate.nonEmpty))

println((fakeValidCertificate.isEmpty))
```

Both prints statements returning false in scala.

My aim is to check for not None `mock[Option[X509Certificate]]` in unit test.

Answer (score 1):

When you work with a mock, you need to pre-program it by telling it which values you want it to return in response to function calls. Depends on the mocking framework you are using, you need to tell it what value you want your `Option` to return when you can `nonEmpty` or `isEmpty` on it.

Having said that, if you are trying to test a function that accepts an `Option[X509Certificate]` and you want to test how it deals with None you can just call it with the value `None`. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but mocking simple values (like integers, Strings, or `Option[T]` for any `T`) is rarely necessary.